# Zlib import error on python 3.5

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, python3, zlib

I started with web development in python(ver:3.5.3) with flask. But when I tried importing zlib getting import error

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Mar 20 2017, 16:01:17) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zlib 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'zlib
```

Tried several approaches found in stack overflow from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741609/install-python-package-locally) as,

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

but this will install in my default python version i.e. 2.7.12. And in that zlib import works without any error.

I also tried below command, which should build the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.5.3
```

but getting below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Any other approach that I will go with ?

Comment: Fix this "E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list" issue buy enabling source code check box in "software and updates". And executed build-dep command again. But still zlib import throwing not found

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` and now try again

Comment: Thanks @George, tried your approach but nothing works. Now I am going ahead by creating virtualenv.

Comment: @napster it could be a problem with python import paths .

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the python in such a way. It includes zlib support

```
./configure --with-zlib
make
sudo make altinstall
```